# What does echo $? do?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, exit-status

In my terminal it printed out a seemingly random number `127`. I think it is printing some variable's value and to check my suspicion, I defined a new variable `v=4`. Running `echo $?` again gave me `0` as output.

I'm confused as I was expecting 4 to be the answer.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-in-shell-scripts

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> $?        Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

`echo $?` will return the exit status of last command. You got `127` that is the exit status of last executed command exited with some error (most probably). Commands on successful completion exit with an exit status of `0` (most probably). The last command gave output `0` since the `echo $v` on the line previous finished without an error.

If you execute the commands

```
v=4
echo $v
echo $?
```

You will get output as:

```
4 (from echo $v)
0 (from echo $?)
```

Also try:

```
true
echo $?
```

You will get `0`.

```
false
echo $?
```

You will get `1`.

The `true` command does nothing, it just exits with a status code `0`; and the `false` command also does nothing, it just exits with a status code indicating failure (i.e. with status code `1`).

Answer (score 5):

**`$?`** is useful in shellscripts as a way to decide what to do depending on how the previous command worked (checking the exit status). We can expect that the exit status is **`0`** when the previous command worked (finished successfully), otherwise a non-zero numerical value.

Demo example:

```
#!/bin/bash

patience=3

read -t "$patience" -p "Press 'Enter' if you run Unix or Linux, otherwise press 'ctrl+d' "

status="$?"

if [[ $status -eq 0 ]]
then
 echo "That's great :-)"
elif [[ $status -eq 1 ]]
then
 echo "(exit status=$status)
You are welcome to try Unix or Linux :-)"
else
 echo "(exit status=$status)
You did not answer within $patience seconds. Anyway :-)"
fi
echo "'Unix & Linux' is a question/answer web site for
Unix and Linux operating systems"
```

You may ask how to run a bash shellscript without Unix or Linux ;-)

Comment: Except that in most cases you can use the command directly in the if-condition, i.e.: `if cmd ... ; then`, instead of `cmd ...; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then`. You really only need `$?` if you need to tell apart three different exit codes.

Comment: @ilkkachu, You are right, and I will modify the demo example according to your comment :-)

Comment: `You may ask how to run a bash shellscript without Unix or Linux` - with a she-bang! ofcourse